# Storing a dictionary generated in the loop and reusing it in a different loop assuming it exists

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7, dictionary

My task is to produce a word game.

The code is rather simple and is defined as follows( ignore the undefined helper function, which will not appear for the sake of brevity):

```
def playGame(wordList):
    """
    Allow the user to play an arbitrary number of hands.

    1) Asks the user to input 'n' or 'r' or 'e'.
      * If the user inputs 'n', let the user play a new (random) hand.
      * If the user inputs 'r', let the user play the last hand again.
      * If the user inputs 'e', exit the game.
      * If the user inputs anything else, tell them their input was invalid.

    2) When done playing the hand, repeat from step 1    
    """
    choice=str(raw_input('Enter n to deal a new hand, r to replay the last hand, or e to end game: '))
    n=7
    previous_hand={}
    hand=dealHand(n)

    while choice!= False:

                    previous_hand=hand.copy()


                    if choice=='n':

                        playHand(hand, wordList, n)


                        choice=str(raw_input('Enter n to deal a new hand, r to replay the last hand, or e to end game: '))

                    elif choice=='r':

                                if len(previous_hand)==0:
                                    print 'You have not played a hand yet. Please play a new hand first!'
                                    choice=str(raw_input('Enter n to deal a new hand, r to replay the last hand, or e to end game: '))

                                else:

                                    playHand(previous_hand, wordList,n)
                                    choice=str(raw_input('Enter n to deal a new hand, r to replay the last hand, or e to end game: '))

                    elif choice=='e':
                            break
                    else:
                        print 'Invalid command.'
                    choice=str(raw_input('Enter n to deal a new hand, r to replay the last hand, or e to end game: '))
```

Everything seems to be working fine except that `'r'` bit. The main trick of this game is that a player can choose to replay a previous hand by inputting `'r'`. Say player started a game, played one hand and then want to repeat exactly same hand (all the letters dealt are the same as previously dealt), and the game allows him/her to do so if a player input `'r'`.

Something like this:

```
Enter n to deal a new hand, r to replay the last hand, or e to end game: n
Current Hand: p z u t t t o
Enter word, or a "." to indicate that you are finished: tot
"tot" earned 9 points. Total: 9 points

Current Hand: p z u t
Enter word, or a "." to indicate that you are finished: .
Goodbye! Total score: 9 points.

Enter n to deal a new hand, r to replay the last hand, or e to end game: r
Current Hand: p z u t t t o
Enter word, or a "." to indicate that you are finished: top
"top" earned 15 points. Total: 15 points
```

However, my code is not working properly on that bit. Everything else is working fine except that. I do not understand how to make a copy of the initial hand, story and then reuse it if player choose `'r'`.

Comment: It seems to be working fine to what you have explained. Can you be a bit more clear about your desires?

Comment: I rolled back your edit from a few minutes ago because it undid all the formatting fixes I'd done. I'm not sure if you had any other changes in there (the diff was messy), if so, please make the changes again, based off of my fixed version.

Comment: looks like you are doing M.I.T 6.00x.

Comment: Yes, I am auditing the course... I went through the first 4 bits in a day and been stuck on this one for 3 days already.

Okay, so to be clear, the game works just fine if I generate a new hand by inputting 'n'. Say the game generates a hand 'p z u t t t o" I play it, input couple of words the game is done and then I input 'r' with intention to play the game again using the same hand (p z u t t t o', but then for some reason my code generates a completely new hand , say ' l t m r k z u '. I want to make sure that 'r' bit is working fine.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham    mate, did you manage to sort yours out?

Comment: I did. It was quite a while ago. I will see if i can track the code down

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  would be nice...

Answer (score 1):

This is from a looong time ago but should work for your M.I.T pset:

```
def playGame(wordList):
    hand = None
    legalIn = ['r','e','n']
    while True:
            user = raw_input("Enter n to deal a new hand, r to replay the last hand, or e to end game: ")
            if user not in legalIn:
                print "Invalid word."
                continue
                #if user inputs r but there have been no hands played yet
            elif user == 'r' and hand is None:
                   print "You have not played a hand yet. Please play a new hand first!"

            elif user == 'n':
                hand = dealHand(n)
                playHand(hand,wordList,n)
            elif user == 'e': # exit game if player inputs e.
                break
            else:
                playHand(hand,wordList, n)




def playHand(hand, wordList, n):
    #  Keep track of the total score
    totalScore = 0
    c = calculateHandlen(hand)
    # As long as there are still letters left in the hand:
    while True:
        if c == 0:
            print "Run out of letters. Total score: {} points.".format(totalScore)
            break
            # Game is over if ran out of letters), so tell user the total score
        # Display the hand
        displayHand(hand)
        # Ask user for input
        word = raw_input("Enter word, or a  '.'  to indicate that you are finished: ") # Ask user for input
        word = word.lower()
        # If the input is a single period:
        if word == '.':
        # End the game (break out of the loop)
            print   "Goodbye! Total score: {} points.".format(totalScore)
            break
            # Otherwise (the input is not a single period):
        # If the word is not valid:
        elif  not isValidWord(word,hand,wordList):
            # Reject invalid word (print a message followed by a blank line)
            print  "Invalid word, please try again."
            print
        # Otherwise (the word is valid):
        else:
            hand = updateHand(hand,word)
            # Tell the user how many points the word earned, and the updated total score, in one line followed by a blank line
            getWordScore(word,n)
            totalScore += getWordScore(word,n)
            print  "{} earned {} points.: {}.".format(word,getWordScore(word,n),totalScore)
            # Update the hand
            c = calculateHandlen(hand)
```

Comment: ,that 'r' bit is still not working. I get a new hand (new combination of letters) instead of previous one.

Anyway, I might give up after days of trying....

Comment: the issue must be in your planHand function

Comment: @LaurynasTribaldovas, I added my playHand it might help you.

Comment: cheers mate! Bloody hell, it is working now but I have yet to realize why. Your playhand could is identical to mine. Anyway, I will try to analyse it and make sure I know why yours is working.

Thanks once again.

Comment: @LaurynasTribaldovas.No worries, glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it. There's only a single variable, `hand`, which is only modified if we're playing a new hand. If we're replaying the previous hand, we just leave it be (unless it's `None`, in that case we reject the input):

```
hand = None

while True:
    choice = raw_input('Enter n to deal a new hand, r to replay the last hand, or e to end game: ')
    if choice == "n":    # deal a new hand
        hand = dealHand(n)
    elif choice == "r":  # reuse the old hand, if there was one
        if hand is None:
            print 'You have not played a hand yet. Please play a new hand first!'
            continue
    elif choice == "e":  # exit
        break
    else:                # any other input
        print 'Invalid command.'
        continue

    playHand(hand)       # actually play here
```

Comment: But where does it store that old hand to be reused? I tried the latter code and it does not work.

If I input 'r' and I played a round of this game before, I want to be able to reuse that previous hand.

Cheers

Comment: @LaurynasTribaldovas The ”old” hand is assigned to `hand` as @Blckknght pointed out that value is never modified during game play.

Comment: Okay I get it but it is still not working. It is the first time I am doing any programming so I am struggling quite a bit.

Comment: @LaurynasTribaldovas: Does your `playhand` function modify the hand you pass to it? If so, that might be the issue. The easiest fix is probably to make it so that it doesn't do any in place modifications, though I suppose you could bring back the `previous_hand` variable if you wanted to make the calling code take care of things.

Comment: I do not think it executes any modifications.  I thought If I use hand.copy() , I will have a copy of the hand to be used in the future...

Comment: @LaurynasTribaldovas: The `copy()` method creates a shallow copy.  Depending on the content of `hand` that might not be enough.